# How to notify android app about the credential given to cyberoam if wifi is connected?

Tags: android

I have created an android app for detecting Internet Connectivity with intent filter "android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" and I get callback in myBroadcastReceiver when wifi is connected and disconnected, but i want to get callbacks for when wifi is getting authorized and when not? Like we have a cyberoam which will restrict access to an internet untill we are putting our credential, so How can i get notified when I am authorized for accessing internet and when not?

Comment: Anyone knows anything that android provide regarding that ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no android event for that. As far as your phone knows you are connected to the network. If the network is not giving you access to internet is another matter. The best you could do is ping a known IP address and see if you get a response. But don't ping too often. Else you may get blocked.